# "Unable to retrieve API" when exporting tenant api using api-import-export in WSO2 api manager

Tags: api, wso2, export, multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to export an api that belongs to a specific tenant in WSO2 api manager.  Here is the `curl` command and output :

```
[Ananke:: 15:47] [~] > curl -H "Authorization:Basic Blablablaredacted"
 -X GET "https://labwso2:9445/api-import-export-v0.9.1/export-api?
name=geo.vdm/GeoTrafic&version=v1.0.0&provider=geoadmin@geo.vdm" -k -vv > GeoTrafic.zip

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 10.96.20.87...
* Connected to labwso2 (labwso2 ip redacted) port 9445 (#0)
* TLS 1.0 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: labwso2
* Server certificate: blablabla
> GET /api-import-export-v0.9.1/export-api?name=geo.vdm/GeoTrafic&version=v1.0.0&provider=geoadmin@geo.vdm HTTP/1.1
> Host: labwso2:9445
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:Basic Blablablaredacted
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
< Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 20:47:34 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 22
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
< 
{ [22 bytes data]
100    22  100    22    0     0    200      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   201
* Connection #0 to host labwso2 left intact
[Ananke:: 15:47] [~] > more GeoTrafic.zip
Unable to retrieve API
[Ananke:: 15:47] [~] >
```

I have used copy copy and paste for api name and version and checked that they are indeed published and functionnal.  I have also tried to tweak the url to add something like /t/geo.vdm to mu link (after importing the importer .war file for the tenant) but to no avail.

How do I specify a tenant api ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue? I deployed the api-import-export war and I checked all the parameters but I'm getting 404 The requested resource .... is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully import an API using import-export tool with below curl command

```
curl -H "Authorization:Basic <base64-encoded-username-and-password-separated-by-a-colon>" -X GET "https://localhost:9443/api-import-export-v0.9.1/export-api?name=testAPI&version=v1&provider=channa@test.com" -k > myAPI.zip
```

Here I had to place the api-import-export-v0.9.1.war file inside /repository/deployment/server/webapps folder.

Please make sure above *.war file is deployed correctly.

I used tenant admin's credentials for exporting the API.

Then I imported the myAPI.zip using following curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -F file=@"/home/channa/Desktop/myAPI.zip" -k -X POST "https://localhost:9443/api-import-export-v0.9.1/import-api?preserveProvider=false"
```

Here I had to use "preserveProvider=false" because I exported the API using a different provider.

If you are not able to solve following above steps please share the carbon stacktrace to investigate further.

Can be found at: /repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Comment: I eventually found it.  I would say the documentation is a bit misleading.  One specifies the tenant by specifying the provider (the user that published or created the API).  But the authentication info passed through the "Authorization:Basic" is the connection information of the admin for the tenant and not the authentication info of the provider.  The doc just put admin everywhere.